# Linux Ubuntu LTS 16.04 - Docker reverts back to new version after restart

Tags: linux, ubuntu, docker, docker-compose

I have installed Docker engine 1.13 on my Ubuntu via this command:

`sudo apt-get install docker-engine=1.13.1~cs6-0~ubuntu-xenial`

But upon restarting my machine, when I `sudo docker info`, I see the installed docker engine as 17.06-ce.

Any idea why does it revert back to 17.06 and how can I permanently restart my machine with 1.13 docker engine?

Comment: run `sudo apt-get remove docker-engine` and then `sudo apt-get purge docker-engine` and then restart, then install old version `sudo apt-get install docker-engine=1.13.1~cs6-0~ubuntu-xenial`

Comment: After the restart step, when I `sudo docker info`, it again showed me 17.06.0-ce. No idea where that came from

Comment: Are you using a VM? If yes on which virtualization software?

Comment: I am not using ubuntu via any VM, I am using Linux Ubuntu LTS 16.04 installed directly on the hardware

Comment: Create file in `/usr/bin/test.txt` with some content and reboot and see if the file still exists, maybe some kind of software is active which reverts changes on reboot

Comment: I did and yes it exists even after restart. Is it not supposed to be there? How do I find out which program is causing that?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154707/discussion-between-tarun-lalwani-and-php-developer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed you have `snap` installed which was providing its own version of docker. When you uninstall `docker-engine`, snap docker was serving 17.06 version.

The solution is to uninstall snapd from the machine and re-install docker engine using

```
sudo apt-get install docker-engine=1.13.1~cs6-0~ubuntu-xenial
```